# how to convert multiple columns and their headers into rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, melt

I have a dataframe with 28 column, 27 of which are datetime columns, 1 of which is an ID column. I need to convert the dataset into 3 total columns where there's one datatime column, a second column with the original header from which the datetime derived, and a third with the original ID from which the datetime derived.

Example of non-transformed data:

```
ID Buy    Sell     Hold 
1  2/2/17 2/3/17   2/4/17
2  3/2/17 3/3/17   3/4/17
3  4/2/17 4/3/17   4/4/17
```

Example of transformed data:

```
Date   Activity ID
2/2/17 Buy      1
2/3/17 Sell     1
2/4/17 Hold     1
3/2/17 Buy      2
3/3/17 Sell     2
3/4/17 Hold     2
4/2/17 Buy      3 
4/3/17 Sell     3 
4/4/17 Hold     3
```

My understanding is that this task can be achieved with pandas `melt`, however is it feasible with 27 datetime columns coupled with a single ID column?

How do I achieve this task with so many dimensions?

Comment: For the ordering you have in your desired output, seems like you want `df.set_index('ID').stack()`, but yes, `melt` will work with that many columns

Comment: good solution, but how would i ensure `ID` is populating each row, that is, along with each event and datetime input? from what I see it's grouping event and datetime by the `ID` once only per `ID`.

Comment: That's just how the representation of a multi-index looks.  If you want them as columns, I guess try `df.set_index('ID').stack().rename_axis(['ID', 'Activity']).rename('Date').reset_index()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use melt:

```
df_melt=df.melt(id_vars='ID',value_vars=['Buy','Sell','Hold'],var_name='Activity',value_name='Date')
```

You can also hyphen your 27 columns with a '_c' for example an then create a list similar to

list=[c for c in df if c.endwith('_c')] and reference the list in the melt function

Comment: If you only supply `id_vars`, the rest of the columns will implicitly be "melted".  ["Column(s) to unpivot. If not specified, uses all columns that are not set as id_vars."](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.melt.html)

Comment: how do i exclude any rows where the original column lacked a row value? ultimately this solution works, but i want to pull any column values which do not equal NaN.